# if statement under for loop

Tags: python, loops, conditional-statements

How to use two if condition statement in a for loop

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]

for i in a:
    if a[0] == 1:
       a[0] = ("Good")
    elif a[3] == 4 
       a[3] == ("Is Good TOo")
```

I want to print out this both, but the loop will stop at `if a[0]==1`
How can I possibly make it like
`a = ['Good',2,3,'Is Good TOo', 5]`

Comment: It's worth noting the brackets are not needed around your strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your bottom line should have only 1 = (1 is for setting the variable, two if for comparing two variables), and your elif needs a : at the end

```
elif a[3] == 4:
    a[3] = ("Is Good TOo")
```

This loop actually would make more sense if you were looping through the index values like this:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
for i in range(0, len(a)):
  if i == 0:
    a[i] = "Good"
  elif i == 3:
    a[i] = "Is Good TOo"
```

Since otherwise the function will fail if you were to have a string index in there to begin with. The above example will always work, based on the index value, which I think is basically what you were aiming for!

Comment: Brilliant!!! @Developer your second solution is what I'm looking for!!! Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your last line.
The correction is

```
a[3] = ("Is Good TOo")
```

In general, == is the comparison operator, and = is the assignment operator